# Convert a string containing hours, minutes, seconds to decimal hours

Tags: vba, excel

I have an automatically generated Excel sheet that has a column containing string values representing time spans. The values have the following format:

```
17 hours, 6 minutes, 16 seconds
```

I need to convert them to show decimal hours (e.g 17.1 hours). How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to use VBA. This worksheet formula will do the trick.

```
=24*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B4," hours, ",":"),
     " minutes, ",":")," seconds",""))
```

This deletes the "seconds" string and replaces the "hours" and "minutes" delimiter strings with the `:` character. `VALUE` then interprets this as a date/time, which evaluates to a fraction of a day; so for your "17 hours, 6 minutes, 16 seconds" example, 0.712685185 days. Multiplying this by 24 gives decimal hours, i.e. 17.1044.

To make this more robust, you could start by `SUBSTITUTE`ing out the spaces, but the above gives you the general idea.

If you must do it in VBA, then I would do it like this:

```
Dim myTimeString As String
Dim splitTime() As String
Dim decimalHours As Double

myTimeString = "17 hours, 6 minutes, 16 seconds"

' Remove useless characters
myTimeString = Trim(Replace(Replace(Replace(myTimeString, " ", ""), _
    ",", ""), "seconds", ""))
' Replace "hours" and "minutes" by a useful delimiter, ":"
myTimeString = Replace(Replace(myTimeString, "minutes", ":"), "hours", ":")
' String now looks like this: "17:6:16". Now split it:
splitTime = Split(myTimeString, ":")

decimalHours = CInt(splitTime(0)) + CInt(splitTime(1)) / 60 + _
    CInt(splitTime(2)) / 3600


' Alternatively, convert the string to a date, then to decimal hours
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = CDate(myTimeString)
decimalHours2 = 24 * CDbl(myDate) ' same result.
```

Comment: Jean, what if the time span had days in it? i tried adding a substitute for day/days, but it didn't work :S

Comment: @MadiD. With days it's the exact same principle. Your solution just needs debugging, which sounds like a new issue, so why don't you ask a new question. Please be more specific about what "didn't work".

Answer (score 2):

There may be better ways, but this is one way of doing it.

```
hours = Trim(Split(timeString, "hours,")(0))
minutes = Trim(Split(Split(timeString, "hours,")(1), " minutes,")(0))
seconds = Trim(Split(Split(Split(timeString,"hours,")(1)," minutes,")(1), "seconds")(0))

TimeInPercentage = CInt(hours) + (1/60) * (CInt(minutes)) + (1/3600) * CInt(seconds)
```