# Excel formula to convert string containing weeks, days, hours to hours

Tags: excel

I usually get excel reports for tracking user effort from a ticketing tool in the below format:

```
3d 5h
1w 2d 6h
```

The above strings are represented in w-weeks, h-hours, d-days. Basically, 1 day here represents 8 hours and 1 week represents 5 days. In the above example, 3d 5h should return "29".

I am looking for an excel formula to convert such values to hours only format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this previous answer will get you part of the way to your actual destination.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326402/convert-a-string-containing-days-hours-and-minutes-into-hhmmss?lq=1

Comment: @DDay This answer doesn't work in my case. In my example, 1 day should translate to 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
Public Function GetTotalHours(r As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String
    s = r.Value2
    s = Replace(s, "w", "*40")
    s = Replace(s, "d", "*8")
    s = Replace(s, "h", "*1")
    s = Replace(s, " ", "+")
    GetTotalHours = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off creating a UDF to perform this.

```
Function GetTotalHours(hourValues As Range) As Long
Dim hourPartsArray
Dim totalHours As Long
Dim i As Integer
    hourPartsArray = Split(hourValues.Value2, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(hourPartsArray)
    Dim tempValue
        If InStr(1, hourPartsArray(i), "w") > 0 Then
            tempValue = Replace(hourPartsArray(i), "w", "")
            totalHours = totalHours + tempValue * 5 * 8
        End If
        If InStr(1, hourPartsArray(i), "d") > 0 Then
            tempValue = Replace(hourPartsArray(i), "d", "")
            totalHours = totalHours + tempValue * 8

        End If
        If InStr(1, hourPartsArray(i), "h") > 0 Then
            tempValue = Replace(hourPartsArray(i), "h", "")
            totalHours = totalHours + tempValue

        End If
    Next i
    GetTotalHours = totalHours
End Function
```

and to use

```
=GetTotalHours(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a formula:

```
="="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"w","*40+"),"d","*8+"),"h","")," ","")
```

Then Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and Replace `=` with `=`.