# Copy comma delimited values into two new rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns and one of the 2 columns has several numbers separated by comma but what I am trying to do is to separate those numbers and insert new line for each of the numbers.  To explain little bit more here is what it looks like:

```
Current issue:
Code1   Code2
2510'   2512 '
0542','0740','5282','5280 '
38101'  3829 '
99812'  9981'
```

After the macro or the VB code is run I would like my result to look like this

```
Desired Results:
Code1   Code2
2510'   2512 '
0542'   5280 '
'0740'  5280 ' 
'5282'  5280 '
38101'  3829 '
99812'  9981'
```

here is the solution i found:  thanks

```
Sub ExpandData()
    Const FirstRow = 2
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & CStr(Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get the values from the worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = Range("A" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":B" & CStr(LastRow))

    ' Get sourcerange values into an array
    Dim Vals() As Variant
    Vals = SourceRange.Value

    ' Loop through the rows in the array and split each comma-delimited list of items and put each on its own row
    Dim ArrIdx As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    For ArrIdx = LBound(Vals, 1) To UBound(Vals, 1)

        Dim CurrCat As String
        CurrCat = Vals(ArrIdx, 1)

        Dim CurrList As String
        CurrList = Replace(Vals(ArrIdx, 2), " ", "")

        Dim ListItems() As String
        ListItems = Split(CurrList, ",")

        Dim ListIdx As Integer
        For ListIdx = LBound(ListItems) To UBound(ListItems)

            Range("A" & CStr(FirstRow + RowCount)).Value = CurrCat
            Range("B" & CStr(FirstRow + RowCount)).Value = ListItems(ListIdx)
            RowCount = RowCount + 1

        Next ListIdx

    Next ArrIdx

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to use the SPLIT function. This can be used in VBA code, or as a worksheet function.

As tigeravatar pointed out, the best thing to do is get something going yourself. You might check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397477/convert-a-string-containing-hours-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-hours-in-msexcel/8399064#8399064). More info on the split function is available from MS [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805572449990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=5202c2f8%2Dbcbf%2D4718%2Da117%2D7afcb8758439).