# Split a filepath on "\"

Tags: string, excel, split, filepath

I'm looking to split a filepath of unknown depth into individual cells.

ex. `if A1 = C:\users\Me\My Documents\Work\9.6.88\` 
  -  this should be split into the following where '||' indicates a cell separation:

```
||  C: || users || Me || My Documents || Work || 9.6.88 ||
```

This function/formula/macro should work for filepaths with any number of subfolders, such that there could also be a cell with just "C:\users\" and that would work too.

Comment: Do you want to repalce A1? Or would you like the exploded file path o start in A2 or is it from B1 over?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great opportunity to use the SPLIT function. This can be used in VBA code, or as a worksheet function.

The best thing to do is get something going yourself. You might check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397477/convert-a-string-containing-hours-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-hours-in-msexcel/8399064#8399064). More info on the split function is available from MS [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805572449990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=5202c2f8%2Dbcbf%2D4718%2Da117%2D7afcb8758439).

Answer (score 1):

Data -> Text to Columns -> Delimited -> type `\` in the Other field -> Finish

Alternately, use this formula in cell B1 and copy right:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"\",REPT(" ",255)),255*(COLUMN(A1)-1)+1,255))
```